# Django dynamic inputs

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, python-3.5

I'd like to create dynamic input system, for example when I enter the folder name - the list of files inside automatically show up  another input ChoiceField below, so I can choose the file. The methods are already written, the problem is - How can I make it in Django view?

Here is my view:

```
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            dir_date = format_date(request.POST['date'])

            files = os.listdir(os.path.join(path+dir_date))
            return render(request, 'inform/show_name.html', {'data': request.POST['your_name'],
                                                             'date': format_date(request.POST['date'])})
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'inform/base.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the form class:

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}))
    flights = forms.ChoiceField(choices=?)
```

Finally, here is my template.

```
{% extends 'inform/header.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <script>
      $( function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( "#anim" ).on( "change", function() {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", $( this ).val() );
        });
      } );
    </script>
    <div class="container" style="color: red; size: auto;">
        <form class="form-vertical" action="get_name" role="form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group" style="display: inherit">
            <center>
                {{form}}
                <input type="submit" value="OK">
            </center>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Is there any way to dynamically read the data from the Date input and give it to the method inside the view without clicking the submit button or creating several others? If it can be solved only by ajax, jQuery or JS, could you please give me a simple sample of how it's done? I'm pretty much frustrated by the inability of creating a simple form.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes it is. And you got it absolutely right that it can be solved by using ajax. I'll show you a short example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you are doing it right. You already know that you need the `on(change)` function for the `datepicker`

Now as soon as the user changes a date, your `on(change)` function is triggered. So all you need to do now is to the get the new date value, which you already have when you do `$( this ).val()`. After that make an `ajax` call to the `url` corresponding to your method `get_name` in views.py

Something like this:

```
$( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#anim" ).on( "change", function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", $( this ).val() );
        send_changed_date_value(variable_with_new_date);
    });
});

function send_changed_date_value(new_date) {
    $.ajax({
       type: // "POST" or "GET", whichever you are using
       url: "/url in urls.py corresponding to get_name method in views.py/",
       data: new_date,

       success: function(response){
            console.log("Success..!!")
       }
    });
}
```

This is how you can send the new date value to your views, everytime it is changed. If you want to submit the complete form data, i.e., `your_name` and `flights` data as well, then you may directly send `serialzed data` of the form in the `data` attribute of `ajax`.

Note -> You will have to return a `HttpResponse` from your `get_name` view as an ajax call requires a **HttpResponse** from the backend to complete the ajax call successfully. You may simply return a string in the response.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give it a try =)

Comment: What about native django way? I googled that it may be possible to add the __init__ class to the form to gain the similar functionality, could you please advice on the matter?

Comment: By **overriding** the `init` function one implements **dynamic django forms** in the backend. According to my understanding,they will work say, for example you have a django form to enter football players info. But if the role of the player is striker, then you add extra fields in the frontend using Javascript dynamically, and when that data is submitted, dynamic fields are added in that django FORM(which you have already defined in the `init` function when you overrode it). But the initial signal of whether he was a striker will be detected by JS and then ajax will tell the same to Django.

Comment: Only then will you process that `player_role` variable in your backend and hence then the extra fields will be included in the form. But again, to detect it from the frontend point of view, like you wanted to detect a change in the **date**, you need JS and then AJAX, to communicate it to the backend. I hope your doubt is cleared after the example I gave you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, m8. Have a great one!